# How to test for undefined doc value - React & Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have dealt with this issue with Firestore/React for a bit where I am trying to load user data in `componentDidMount()` from Firestore from a value that doesn't exist in the document.  The only way I know how to fix this is by initializing all values for a given object to empty even if they are not being used yet. Such as setting `currentWorker` object as I did below:

```
tickets: { 
  ID12345: {
    title: "example title",
    currentWorker: {
       name: ""
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to leave it undefined until it's needed as I do simply below:

```
tickets: { 
  ID12345: {
    "example title"
  }
}
```

Only problem for this case is that I do not know how to test for `currentWorker` object being set without throwing a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. I have tried to test for undefined objects in multiple ways like I do in the example below, but I get the same error.

```
if (typeof(doc.data().currentWorker.name ) !== 'undefined' || doc.data().currentWorker.name != null) {
  firestore.collection("tickets").doc(doc.data().currentWorker.name )
.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({
          worker: doc.data()
        })
      }
  } else {
      console.log("Grabbing currentWorkerfailed");
  }
}.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error grabbing currentWorker: ", error);
});
} else {
  console.log('Undefined or Null')
}
```

How do I test for a non-existent object in a document without throwing this error? Or do I always need to initialize documents with the fields I want to test for in my React app?

Comment: Your code is just checking `name`, but you should be first checking `currentWorker` before checking `name` on it.

Comment: Wow okay yeah that's all it was, seems obvious enough now that you say it haha. Thanks Doug